# C GUI program crashes during runtime

Tags: c, user-interface, sqlite, runtime-error

I'm writing a C GUI program using graphApp GUI library and this code segment cause my program to crash:

```
...
char *str,*sql;

// Read input from text field
str = get_control_text(event_name);

// Insert into database
sprintf(sql,"INSERT INTO event VALUES('%s');",str);
db_status = sqlite3_exec(db,sql,0,0,&mssg);
```

The `get_control_text()` is used to read data from a text field and its return type is `char *`. When I input a string, the program terminate normally, but if the string contains spaces, the program will crash after inserting the data into database. Can someone please help me to find out what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where is `sql` initialized? (also, use a debug like `gdb`, it's your friend) :)

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten to allocate memory for `sql`.

Comment: Sheesh.  Is a crash all you get?  You'd think the compiler would at least grace us with a warning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It will if you turn on some more warnings. For example, on gcc -Wall: test.c:9:12: warning: ‘sql’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Comment: To avoid such errors (*and* SQL injection attacks), use [sqlite3_mprintf](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html).